# Is it possible to use Java5 level annotations to generate EMF using "annotated Java"?

Tags: java, annotations, eclipse-emf

I've recently discovered that it was possible to use [annotated Java code to generate an EMF model](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/docs/2.x/tutorials/clibmod/clibmod_emf2.0.html#step1b). However, I was stunned by the fact that this annotated Java code use javadoc annotations, that are not compiled, and as a consequence of very little interest.

So, is it possible to use Java5 level annotations instead ?

**EDIT** [According to Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.emf.doc/tutorials/clibmod/clibmod.html#step1b), it seems possible to use Java5 code, but no Java5 annotations seems to be provided ... is it really the case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible. The current Java importer only looks at JavaDoc annotations, not Java5 annotations.